# Hide an UL list only, when mouse cursor is took away

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu:

```
<ul id="littlemenu">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
</ul>

    $('#littlemenu').mouseout(function() {
        $('#littlemenu').fadeOut();
        $('#littlemenutri').hide();
    });

li
{
    background-color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5CVFa/

it is hidden by default, and shows when clicked at something. So, you move the cursor to this list, but as soon as you choose another LI, it disappears. But I only attached to UL that mouseout() function, not to LI, still it disappears. I only want to hide it when you move away the cursor from the UL, not from a LI

Comment: Would help if you show some JS code here.

Comment: without a single line of code, how could we help you??

Comment: ok, done, I thought it was easy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) event instead of the `mouseout` event.

> The mouseleave event differs from mouseout in the way it handles event
>   bubbling. If mouseout were used in this example, then when the mouse
>   pointer moved out of the Inner element, the handler would be
>   triggered. This is usually undesirable behavior. The mouseleave event,
>   on the other hand, only triggers its handler when the mouse leaves the
>   element it is bound to, not a descendant. So in this example, the
>   handler is triggered when the mouse leaves the Outer element, but not
>   the Inner element.

http://jsfiddle.net/Bz8DP/

```
$('#littlemenu').mouseleave(function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that mouseout() isn't the right function for what you want to achieve. Try [mouseleave()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)